# connectJS sessions - secure true vs false

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express/connectJS and playing around with sessions. The ConnectJS [documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) provides a simple view counter, and this works for me.

However, it stops working if I set the cookie option 'secure:true', like so...

```
app.use(express.session({key:'NodeJS', secret:'cookie', cookie:{maxAge:3600000, secure:true}}));
```

What I see is the sessionID is only sent in the request if 'secure:false'.   If 'secure:true', I get a new sessID with every request.

This fails.

```
Req header - SECURE:TRUE
Cookie connect.sid=s%3AP2q10tK255KdVcizJMwETG69.IU2idEzOVaCxahdcRoEGhTkUBK%2B1Evxc0boj97nJgHg;
connect.sess=s%3Aj%3A%7B%7D.opP3ZU2IoVMmmqws%2F5vFGB4s8FNXJ8R6RNZoF4KRNfU
```

This works.

```
Req header - SECURE:FALSE 
Cookie connect.sid=s%3AP2q10tK255KdVcizJMwETG69.IU2idEzOVaCxahdcRoEGhTkUBK%2B1Evxc0boj97nJgHg;
connect.sess=s%3Aj%3A%7B%7D.opP3ZU2IoVMmmqws%2F5vFGB4s8FNXJ8R6RNZoF4KRNfU;
NodeJS=s%3ArBKqb-Wptr_IJMYW6VzJVu__.2Yc3GL32L%2BHuY4L5RxepdiEirtvbSlIeErWVIHXm4uc
```

Can someone briefly explain what's going on here, or point me to good explanation?

============= **FOLLOW UP** ==============

The session option 'secure' toggles using either http or https.

Now, there are two types of session management: session, and cookieSession. Below is the output from each of these:

SESSION

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({key:'NodeJS', secret:'cookie', cookie:{maxAge:3600000, secure:false}}));

=== req.sessionID ===
b1t73i-MjbyPfQaZHo7_0aGn

==== req.sessionStore ===
{ sessions: { 'b1t73i-MjbyPfQaZHo7_0aGn': '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":3600000,"expires":"2013-08-12T19:13:37.169Z","secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"views":1}' } generate: [Function], _events: { disconnect: [Function], connect: [Function] } }

=== req.session ===
{ cookie: { path: '/', _expires: Mon Aug 12 2013 12:13:37 GMT-0700 (PDT), originalMaxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: false }, views: 1 }

==== req.cookies ===
{ NodeJS: 's:b1t73i-MjbyPfQaZHo7_0aGn.RDYYqfFjjAYFry9PmQW/fih+PPMTgNK6uwy5EW372CE', woot: 'woot' }

=== req.signedCookies ===
{ swoot: 'swoot' }
```

COOKIESESSION

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({key:'NodeJS', secret:'cookie', cookie:{maxAge:3600000, secure:false}}));

=== req.sessionID ===
undefined

==== req.sessionStore ===
undefined

=== req.session ===
{ views: 1, cookie: { path: '/', _expires: Mon Aug 12 2013 12:20:16 GMT-0700 (PDT), originalMaxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: false } }

==== req.cookies ===
{ NodeJS: 's:j:{"views":1}.JtWQMoqzLEZBoGSxbxXfyqFJ2KIYyJG9GDSY4rxdVLQ', woot: 'woot' }

=== req.signedCookies ===
{ swoot: 'swoot' }
```

SESSION returns objects I can work with, but how should I handle SESSIONCOOKIE?

Comment: Please use the code sample tags for formatting and not br, b tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In connect/express the sessionID would be `req.sessionID`. See documentation [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).

`connect.sid` would be cookie signature, which serves as the default key for decrypting the express cookie. If you give `key` option, this would be used for decrypting the cookie. When secure is turned on it keeps on changing the `connect.sid`. This is a feature in https to stop cookie sniffing/stealing. `connect.sid` consists of the sessionID itself plus some hash.

#### Update:

As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/qZwiwBsJZ04), you can get the session id from the sid (from s: to .). For eg:

```
sid : 's:b1t73i-MjbyPfQaZHo7_0aGn.RDYYqfFjjAYFry9PmQW/fih+PPMTgNK6uwy5EW372CE'
sessionid : b1t73i-MjbyPfQaZHo7_0aGn
```

You will see that the sessionid is a key for the session in your sessionstore.

Also **session** is different from **cookiesession**. In session your cookie stores sid key which is used to decrypt and get the session. cookiesession means cookie only session, there is no session stored on the server. The cookie itself is the session, which is encrypted with your key. So don't mix them up. Your original question was related to session. cookiesession is useful only when session data is small and cookie is signed with a secret key. See this [article](http://benatkin.com/2012/05/23/cookie-session-store-connec/).

Comment: ....per @Nitzan Shaked, I'm going with 'secure:false' for HTTP.  I can access req.sessionID using Connect's session like so: express.session({....}), but using express.cookieSession, there is no 'sessionID'.  I only see the ID value in 'req.cookies'.   How can the session ID value get parsed out of that?

Answer (score 1):

What's your URL endpoint? Is it http:// or https:// ? Using cookies for the session, if the cookies are "secure" then they won't get sent to the server *unless* it's https. The server then never sees the cookie, can't associate the connection to a session, and thus creates a new session.

Comment: that makes sense, and i'm under HTTP.